# How to remove hidden Google contacts

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

How can I remove people from the seemingly hidden contacts list Google keeps for me? For instance Google Play keeps showing me suggestions and reviews of apps from a person who is not in my contacts but who I emailed once or twice 4 years ago.

Similarly, in Gmail I get suggestions for email addresses I haven't had contact with for nearly 10 years, but I don't know how to remove these because they aren't listed in my contacts.

Comment: Are you looking at your contacts list at https://www.google.com/contacts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point it's not possible.

Google Contacts has a suggested contacts features which doesn't have enable / disable option at this point.

So any time you email somebody Google contacts adds them as you suggested contacts so when you look at your contacts you see them as a contacts. Even the people you emailed once.

You can check Google Forums.

Also, these types of questions could be posted on Google Forums:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/apps